# How to get lineitem sponsorship

Tags: php, google-dfp

How to get line-item sponsorship value ie.a percentage of all the impressions that are being sold are reserved of each line item?

I'm using DFP PHP client library v201711.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [LineItemService.getLineItemsByStatement](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201711/LineItemService#getlineitemsbystatement) to query DFP API and then inspect the [primaryGoal](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201711/LineItemService.Goal) attribute. This is how it would look like in an [online DFP API query tool](https://dfp-playground.appspot.com/) for a 50% sponsorship line item:

```
{
  "primaryGoal": {
    "units": 50,
    "goalType": "DAILY",
    "unitType": "IMPRESSIONS"
  },
  "orderId": 548040886,
  "reserveAtCreation": false,
  "adExchangeAuctionOpeningPriority": 0,
  "isPrioritizedPreferredDealsEnabled": false,
  "startDateTimeType": "USE_START_DATE_TIME",
  "skipCrossSellingRuleWarningChecks": false,
  "costPerUnit": {
    "currencyCode": "RUB",
    "microAmount": 200000000
  },
  ...
}
```